# How to make router's log-in pop-up?

Tags: login, user-interface, popups

When I go to my router's log-in page(192.168.xxx.xxx), there is a non-HTML and non-CSS pop-up. How do I make it?

Comment: This popup is generated by the browser and is probably as a result of a .htaccess rule. Does it look like this: http://itsmereal.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/google-chrome-htpasswd.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I would suspect a pop up is actually simply an alert, created in JavaScript

Since you ask how to make it, An alert is created like:

```
alert("Hello world");
```

However, I would guess yours will be more "prompt" like, something like

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var ip = prompt("Please enter your IP", "");
}
</script>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ew6tdo1e/)